# What is the difference between the two 'Story Mission' Icons?

Tags: destiny

On Destiny, there appears to be two different icons for story missions:

- one slightly smaller with just a star (e.g. Earth - The Dark Within).
- one larger with a star within 'wings' (e.g. Earth - Restoration)

What do these different icons represent?

See the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The star with wings is a main story mission, often playing a huge part in the story with a cutscene or other grand event.

The single star mission is more of a sidemission. There is no requirement to complete them, but they do offer more story and, of course, rewards.

Comment: often the wing ones are also a bit longer